# Python input to select specific rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe where I would like to utilize Input function to select a row or a group of rows.

**Data**

```
type    stat    country
aa1     y       ca
bb2     n       ny
cc3     y       tx
```

**Desired**

```
Use Input("select type value:  ")

type in:  aa1, bb2

*selects appropriate rows

type    stat    country 
aa1     y       ca  
bb2     n       ny
```

**Doing**

```
out = Input("select type value:  ")
df.loc[df['type'].isin([aa1, bb2])]
```

I am thinking that I can combine .loc along w input()
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `query`:

```
out = input("select type value:  ")
vals = [v.strip() for v in out.split(',')]
df1 = df.query('type.isin(@vals)')
print(df1)
```

Ouput

```
select type value:  aa1,bb2

  type stat country
0  aa1    y      ca
1  bb2    n      ny
```

**Update**

> Is there a way to capture the remaining dataset? once selected (The subset that was not sliced)

Use a boolean mask:

```
out = input("select type value:  ")
vals = [v.strip() for v in out.split(',')]

mask = df['type'].isin(vals)
df1 = df.loc[mask]
df2 = df.loc[~mask]
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
  type stat country
0  aa1    y      ca
1  bb2    n      ny

>>> df2
  type stat country
2  cc3    y      tx
```

Comment: ok tried this and this works- I need to research v strip - is this unique in performing queries within Python @corralien

Comment: `v` is a string and `strip` a method of str type to return the string with leading and trailing characters (by default whitespace) removed.

Comment: @Corralien- is there a way to capture the remaining dataset? once selected (The subset that was not sliced)

Answer (score 2):

Because input is strings with `,` only use `split` for list `['aa1','bb2']` with strip for remove traliling spaces, because type `aa1,bb2` not `aa1, bb2` like mentioned in question:

```
df[df['type'].isin([x.strip() for x in out.split(',')])]
```

Comment: Thank you - does this incorporate the input() function?

Comment: @Lynn - can you try `df[df['type'].isin(Input("select type value:  ").split(', '))]` ?

Comment: thank you - it subsets for a single entry - but when I try and enter  aa1,bb2 the result is just the header

Comment: @Lynn - hmmm, if singlr input what is `out = input("select type value:  ")` `print (out.split(', '))` ?

Comment: it shows this: ['aa1,bb2'] - subsets, but doesn't retain the rest of the col values

Comment: @Lynn - because there is space `, `.

Comment: @Lynn - and in question is type `aa1, bb2`, in real `aa1,bb2` - no space after `,`